# Should I import flask.ext.sqlalchemy or flask_sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

When I learned Flask, I found some examples used `flask.ext.sqlalchemy` and some used `flask_sqlalchemy`. Which one should be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Flask Extension Development](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/extensiondev/) guide says:

> As of Flask 0.11, most Flask extensions have transitioned to the new
>   naming schema. The flask.ext.foo compatibility alias is still in Flask
>   0.11 but is now deprecated – you should use flask_foo.

Comment: @陈诗锋 if it answers your question, please mark the answer as accepted. It will probably help other people searching for this question too